# Select records that have same value in a column and different in another

Tags: sqlite, having

In my table `INVENTORY` there are 3 columns `varchar` code, version, description.
e.g

```
code  || version || description
--------------------------
AS100 ||   01    || description
AS100 ||   02    || description
AS100 ||   02    || description
AS100 ||   02    || description
AS200 ||   01    || description
AS300 ||   01    || description
AS300 ||   01    || description
```

I want to select all those products that have the same product and multiple versions. In the above table, this query would returned:

`AS100` - `01` - `description`
`AS100` - `02` - `description`

I tried to use `HAVING` statement but I don't get the above result..

For example, I tried this:

```
SELECT code, version, Count(*) FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY version
HAVING Count(*) =1
```

but it returns all the codes which appears once.

I created an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a4e7/1) here (I hope it plays, sometimes the page freezes)
A small dump of my DB

```
CREATE TABLE "INVENTORY" (
    "code" VARCHAR, 
    "version" VARCHAR,
    "description" VARCHAR
)


INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS100", "01", "description");
INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS100", "02", "description");
INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS100", "02", "description");
INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS100", "02", "description");
INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS200", "02", "description");
INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS300", "01", "description");
INSERT INTO INVENTORY (code, version, description) VALUES("AS300", "01", "description");
```

Comment: @kiner_shah I tried the solutions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456747/sqlite-get-records-with-same-column-value with variant ways.

Comment: What result you are getting for your query?

Comment: Try GROUP BY, it will group the data defending on the column
SELECT * from INVENTORY GROUP BY version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
select *, count(*) from (select * from INVENTORY group by code, version)
group by code
having count(*)>1
```

That is, first make a table aggregated by the two columns of interest, then choose the rows from this table where there are at least two distinct values of **code**.